# Number pad produces strange output in certain commands in Terminal

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal, vi

Running OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

Well, something happened to my system (I can honestly say it wasn't me but), I was unable to use the USB keyboard number pad while using commands such as 'less', 'more' (and perhaps 'vim' and 'nano') in the OS X Terminal.  It would type output `ESCOq` for 1, `ESCOr` for 2, `ESCOs` for 3, ..., `ESCOp` for 0.  When exiting the programs, the USB keyboard number pad would work just fine in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Terminal -> Preferences -> Profile -> Advanced, and uncheck 'Allow VT100 application keypad mode'.